# How to force log4j load xml config from non src folder?

Tags: java, xml, log4j

Is it possible to have log4j.xml loaded from a different dir than source root and how? (programmatically?) Meaning that it's somewhere in FS not just in classpath.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [DOMConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html) you can specify the the XML file used to configure log4j.

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("/path/to/log4j.xml");
```

For log4j.properties you can do the same thing with [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("/path/to/log4j.properties");
```

Comment: And what if it's log4j.properties?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the best way, but you can specify the location of the file by setting the java property log4j.configuration=path/to/config/file. For example, you can specify this directly to the java command with `java -Dlog4j.configuration=path`.