# Extending log4j Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I have application which heavily use log4j out of the box. This uses lots of third party APIs. Some of these third party API completely hacks our logger and wipes out our appenders sometimes completely gets initialized with different configuration and we completely loose our logging capabilities!!

Any ideas why log4j can be hacked so easily? if we need to solve this we have to re-write log4j implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4J is 'hacked' so easily because it has no way to distinguish between the application configuration which is expected to configure log4j and some library developer who doesn't understand the basics of log4j and configures it inside a library.

I think you have several options:

1. Find out when your libraries mangle the log4j configuration and make sure you overwrite that configuration afterwards.
2. Submit a bug for the malbehaving libraries, in case of open source you might even submit a patch yourself, with the additional option to use that patch, no matter if it is included in the official distribution.
3. Make everything loading Log4J classes in your application use a special classloader, e.g. by using OSGI or by building you own LoggerFactory, which loads the log4j LoggerFactory with a special classloader. The library obviously wouldn't do that and thereby get their own set of Log4J classes and whatever they do to the configuration wouldn't affect you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting your logger into a different class loader?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the solution of configuring your log4j on startup, reffering to the correct location. That should be doable:

- either using approach mentioned by @Mark here: [How to force log4j load xml config from non src folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689887/how-to-force-log4j-load-xml-config-from-non-src-folder)
- or the one by @Jon7 here: [How to force log4j load xml config from non src folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689887/how-to-force-log4j-load-xml-config-from-non-src-folder)
- or by approach mentioned on: [Best Practice on Configuring Log4j Properties Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825414/best-practice-on-configuring-log4j-properties-path)

I'd give them a try one by one and see if any of these would solve the problem.

The only thing is that in case you have multiple such a config files, in case the 1.st approach is your way, you might need to call `resetConfiguration()` prio to `configure()`, as the javadoc says:
"The existing configuration is not cleared nor reset."

you might need to call prio to that:

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration()
```

so either:

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
DOMConfigurator.configure("/path/to/log4j.xml");
```

or:

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure("/path/to/log4j.properties");
```